# Why passing function as &name and name gives different pointers?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a function which I want to call another function and print its name and handle its results. It works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::map<void *, std::string> ptr_map;
#define IS_API_CALL(fun) ptr_map[fun] = __FUNCTION__;

int api_call_bar(double x) {
    IS_API_CALL(&api_call_bar);
    return 0;
}

std::string getFuncNameByPtr(void * addr) {
    for (auto it = ptr_map.begin(); it != ptr_map.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->first == addr) return it->second;
    }

    return "???";
}

template <typename... Args>
void api_exec(int func(Args...), Args... args) {
    func(args...);
    auto name = getFuncNameByPtr(func); // <-- HERE. &func doesnt work
    std::cout << name << " was called\n";
}

int main() {
    api_exec(&api_call_bar, 2.0);
}
```

This one prints `api_call_bar was called` which is fine. The interesting part for me is part marked `<-- HERE`. If I pass it as `&func` it doesn't work properly anymore(name is not found by pointer in a map). Why is it so? I think it should be exactly the same.

Comment: _"I think it should be exactly the same."_ Why's that? And why are you converting function pointers to `void*` and back again? I don't remember whether that's allowed, which is in itself a good enough reason not to do it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because &func and func should evaluate to the same pointer? no?

Comment: funny how you _don't_ use map capabilities...

Comment: No. &func is already a pointer of func. If you take a pointer of &func you get a func pointer pointer - func**. pointer to a pointer of func != pointer to a func

Comment: @tambre thanks. That was the issue :D silly me

Comment: Anyway: A conversion of a function pointer to void* is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting hit by the implicit conversion to pointer for function argument declarations.  Since you can't actually pass a function as an argument to a function, the compiler (silently -- IMHO should at least be a warning) converts the function type to a pointer type.  So when you declare:

```
void api_exec(int func(Args...), Args... args)
```

it's really as if you declared

```
void api_exec(int (*func)(Args...), Args... args)
```

which means that when you use `&func` in `api_exec`, you're getting a pointer to the argument (so a pointer to a pointer), not the value of the argument.

The same thing happens with arrays, which also confuses people who don't realize it.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: defining `func` as a reference to a function (`int (&func)(Args...)`) would have avoided the whole problem.

Comment: It *would* make more sense for the language to treat a function-type argument as a reference instead of a pointer, but C++ tries to be compatible with C, which doesn't have references...